# Shorten the length of an arrow in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw a picture representing a control theory graph.

I am pretty much there, but there are two problems:

1. I need to have a dot above the x(t) in the first equation in the big box. When I put it in maths mode, it draws four lines instead of two, or, depending on how I split the maths mode, it puts it all on one line. Any ideas on how to get that damned dot above the x without changing the layout of the box?
2. The RHS arrow with the y(.) above it is too long. I would like to get it back down to a length close to the LHS arrow with the v(.), it would just look nicer!

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=6em, minimum width=12em]

\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=2cm]

\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]

\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=4cm,>=latex']
    \node [input, name=input] {};

    \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {B};

    \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {\begin{array} \dot{x}(t)=&Ax(t)+Bu(t)\\ x(0)=&x_0 \end{array}};

    !\node [sum, right of=controller, node distance=3.651cm] (mat) {C};
    \node [sum, below of=controller] (K) {K};
    \node [output, right of=controller] (output) {C};
    \node [input, name=end, right of=output, node distance=5cm] {};
    \coordinate [below of=sum] (measurements) {};
    \coordinate [right of=output](fin) {};
    \coordinate[left of =output, xshift=2.7cm] (nodek) {};
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$v(\bullet)$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$u(\bullet)$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=(x)] {$x(\bullet)$} (mat) {};
    \draw [->] (output) -- node {$y(\bullet)$} (fin);
    \draw [-] (nodek) |- (K);
    \draw [->] (K) -| (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [jak123's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73830/jak123) but with some slight differences:

- Rather than introducing a new length `\mywidth` I make use of the `node distance=2cm` key.
- I also switch to the `\tikzset` syntax instead of `\tikzstyle`.
- I drop superfluous elements of the code.

Here is what went wrong in your code

- You forgot to add the column specifiers in the array, which is why it did not work.
- You were loading but not using the positioning library.
- Several coordinates were redundant.

So here is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=6em, minimum width=12em},
sum/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=2cm},
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate}}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    \node [input, name=input] {};

    \node [sum, right= of input] (sum) {B};

    \node [block, right=of sum,align=left] (controller) 
    {$\begin{array}{r@{\,}l} \dot{x}(t)=&Ax(t)+Bu(t)\\ x(0)=&x_0 \end{array}$};

    \node [sum, right=of controller] (mat) {C};
    \node [sum, below=1cm of controller] (K) {K};
    \coordinate [below=of sum] (measurements) {};
    \coordinate [right=1.5cm of mat](fin) {};
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$v(\bullet)$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$u(\bullet)$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=x,above,midway] {$x(\bullet)$} 
    coordinate[midway] (x) (mat);
    \draw [->] (mat) -- node[midway,above] {$y(\bullet)$} (fin);
    \draw [-] (x) |- (K);
    \draw [->] (K) -| (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}
\newlength{\mywidth}
\setlength{\mywidth}{2cm}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=6em, minimum width=12em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=2cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=4cm,>=latex']
    \node [input, name=input] {};
    \node [sum, right=\mywidth of input] (sum) {B};
    \node [block, right=\mywidth of sum] (controller) {$\begin{array}{ccc} \dot{x}(t)&=&Ax(t)+Bu(t)\\ x(0)&=&x_0 \end{array}$};
    \node [sum, right=\mywidth of controller] (mat) {C};
    \node [sum, below=1cm of controller] (K) {K};
    \node [output, right=\mywidth of controller] (output) {C};
    \node [input, name=end, right=\mywidth of output] {};
    \coordinate [below=\mywidth of sum] (measurements) {};
    \coordinate [right=\mywidth of output] (fin) {};
    \coordinate[left = \mywidth/2 of output] (nodek) {};
    \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$v(\bullet)$} (sum);
    \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$u(\bullet)$} (controller);
    \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=(x)] {$x(\bullet)$} (mat) {};
    \draw [->] (mat) -- node {$y(\bullet)$} (fin);
    \draw [-] (nodek) |- (K);
    \draw [->] (K) -| (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: y]

Comment: Despite the warning, I have to thank you! I spent ages on that, and now, it works! <3